# Close corresponding ProcessStart application upon closing Tab Control

Tags: c#, winforms

For every tabs created, an application is opened. I'm able to close the tab itself but the application is still running when I check task Manager.

[image: tabs]

How can I identify what application to close when I close a certain tab?

For example there are 3 tabs, when I close tab 2, it should only kill the application running on tab 2.

I can kill all upon win form close:

```
Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad"); 
foreach (Process p in localByName)              
       p.Kill();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a class to run and store the tabName and PID of the process

```
public class myProcess
{
  private static Hashtable _sessions;

  public static Hashtable sessions
  {
     get { return _sessions; }
     set { _sessions = value; }
  }

  public static void run(string name, string _Process) 
  {
     Process p = Process.Start(name, _Process);
     sessions.Add(name, p.Id);
     p.WaitForInputIdle();
  }
}
```

On Form load:

```
myProcess.sessions = new Hashtable();
```

On Tab creation:

```
ctr++;
String name = box + ctr;

TabPage tp = new TabPage(name);

Panel tb = new Panel();
tb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
tp.Controls.Add(tb);
myTab.TabPages.Add(tp);
myTab.SelectedTab = tp;
tp.Name = name;

myProcess.run(name, "Notepad")
```

Then upon closing the tab, get the tabName and kill the process

```
String tabName = myTab.SelectedTab.Name;                   

int PID = Int32.Parse(myProcess.sessions[tabName].ToString() );
Process sTab = Process.GetProcessById(PID);
sTab.Kill();
```

Answer (score 1):

Store a reference to your started process in your tab pages `Tag` property:

```
TabPage tabpage = new TabPage();
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabpage);
tabpage.Tag = Process.Start("notepad");
```

Now when you close the tab you need to get a reference to the tab page you're closing, cast the `Tag` to a `Process` and call `Kill()`:

```
Process processtoremove = (Process)tabpagebeingremoved.Tag;
processtoremove.Kill();
```

Comment: Could you mark my question as the answer if it's the correct one?